# What SQLite to use with nodejs

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am developing application using `node.js`. In that I am willing to use `SQLite` as embedded database. I searched online for `SQLite` npm modules. I found various modules:

1. https://github.com/grumdrig/node-sqlite
2. https://github.com/orlandov/node-sqlite
3. https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3

From documentation and other sources, I understood that (1) operates synchronously, while (2) and (3) works asynchronously. So, I dropped the plan to use (1).

Now, I want to know what is the difference between (2) and (3) and which one should be preferred? I googled a lot but could not find much to help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3. It's asynchronous (almost a must-have), it's the most actively maintained, and it has the most stars on GitHub.

Comment: Hasn't been updated in about a year.  So not the most active.

Comment: Updated to Node 8 just recently (5th August 2017 at the time of this writing).

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, you could use a javascript embedded database. This way you just need to declare the database as a dependency in your `package.json` and `require()` it in your application.

Check out [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) (which I wrote) or [nStore](https://github.com/creationix/nstore) for example.

Comment: Check out also FinalDB (https://www.npmjs.org/package/final-db) as an another embedded db solution.

Comment: These are probably the best solutions for document based databases.

Answer (score 13):

For my architecture synchronous `better-sqlite3` appeared to be better:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3

- Full transaction support
- Geared for performance, efficiency, and safety
- Easy-to-use synchronous API (faster than an asynchronous API)
- Custom SQL function support
- 64-bit integer support (invisible until you need it)

Comment: Wouldn't these synchronous calls block the main thread? Like if you have an application that deals with precise timing, it would be randomly freezing when you perform sql queries, wouldn't it? And each insert/update requires IO operations, right?

Answer (score 5):

#### [SQLite Client for Node.js Apps](https://github.com/kriasoft/node-sqlite) /w built-in SQL-based migrations API

[image: NPM version] [image: NPM downloads] [image: Online Chat]

```js
import express from 'express';
import db from 'sqlite';                                       // <=
import Promise from 'bluebird';

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/posts', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const posts = await db.all('SELECT * FROM Post LIMIT 10'); // <=
    res.send(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});

Promise.resolve()
  // First, try to open the database
  .then(() => db.open('./database.sqlite', { Promise })        // <=
  // Update db schema to the latest version using SQL-based migrations
  .then(() => db.migrate({ force: 'last' })                    // <=
  // Display error message if something went wrong
  .catch((err) => console.error(err.stack))
  // Finally, launch the Node.js app
  .finally(() => app.listen(port));
```

**NOTE**: The example above only works with [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) v6 and newer (assuming that [`import`](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) and [`async/await`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) language features used in the code are transpalied with [Babel](https://babeljs.io)). For earlier versions of Node.js use `var db = require('sqlite/legacy');`.

Comment: This implementation made my app more interesting. Thanks! :)

Comment: Here the link to your article about that https://medium.com/@tarkus/node-js-and-sqlite-for-rapid-prototyping-bc9cf1f26f10

Answer (score 1):

I have switched from https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3 to https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3. One of reasons is better-sqlites author gave me a thorough answer, https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/issues/181, about why https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3#why-should-i-use-this-instead-of-node-sqlite3

Answer (score -1):

Grumdrig's module seems to be the one referenced the most on Stack Overflow, and on other sites as well.

Also, the documentation is pretty good: http://github.grumdrig.com/node-sqlite/

I have rather little experience with Node SQLite, but the community seems to have chosen.

Comment: Don't use this one (mine). It's old, abandoned, and only synchronous.